# Can the facts literally speak for themselves?

Tags: idioms

Can the facts literally *[speak](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speak#English) for themselves*, or is that phrase figurative? I'm unsure, because I'm not sure whether 'speak' or 'speak for' always involves speech.

---

In the [OED entry for 'speak'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speak#English) (subscription required) (there is no entry for the idiom):

> 6. a. fig. Of things: To be expressive or significant; to make some revelation or disclosure.

This is figurative. However, 15a seems to cover it

> 15. a. To indicate, denote, or betoken; to reveal, make known. 
>       1856   R. W. Emerson Eng. Traits iii. 40
>       The solidity of the
>       structures..speaks the industry of ages

But that is transitive, and I think that there's no direct object in that phrase.

However, there is also an entry to "speak for"

> 4. To indicate; to betoken.
>
> 1832   Philol. Museum I. 335   The great mass of evidence that speaks for an intimate affinity between the Pelasgians and the Hellenes.

So it could be literal, but says something slightly weird, that the facts indicate or are in some sense a sign of themselves, perhaps their being facts.

Comment: Are you asking about the expression _The facts speak for themselves_ or about _The facts literally speak for themselves_? if you are asking about usage of the word _literally_, there are plenty of questions and answers elsewhere on this site: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=literally

Comment: i am asking whether the phrase *facts speak for themselves* can be literal.

Comment: not unless you are listening to a talking book.

Comment: Yes. Why should you be unsure? Have you tried to look up the meaning and usage of the idiomatic expression?

Comment: Try expressing your question in different words. Link to the dictionary entries you've looked up, add an example or two where you think "speak" is used in the literal sense to mean something other than *saying words*, etc.

Comment: i do that in my answer @Lawrence

Comment: @user3293056 On EL&U, dictionary entries count as "research" and are expected to be in the question text.

Comment: oh ok, well i checked wiktionary, before the oed, and it didn't make sense. i'll link to it @Lawrence

Comment: So you are genuinely wondering whether a fact is a living creature with a mouth and vocal cords. I suggest that you start by looking up what a fact is. Spoiler alert: no, it does not have a mouth. It does not even exist in the physical world at all. It is an abstract concept. It literally cannot do anything. It can't speak, it can't swim, it can't fall in love, it can't buy a burger, it can't read this question and scratch its head. It can't do anything at all. Literally.

Comment: Can you explain in what sense the phrase could be argued to be considered literal?

Comment: @Lawrence did you read my answer, that explains

Comment: If I say, "I have two children," and my two children then say in unison, "The facts speak for themselves," I suppose you could argue that the expression is literal in that case—but it's a pretty contrived situation.

Answer (score 2):

Facts can certainly speak for themselves:

> **speak for itself and speak for themselves**
>   [for something] not to need explaining; to have an obvious meaning. *The facts speak for
>   themselves. Tom is guilty. Your results speak for themselves. You need
>   to work harder.*
>   [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/speaks+for+themselves)

However, such usage is figurative, not literal. Your use of the term *literal* is misplaced and confusing.

Comment: why is my use of literal confusing? i am completely aware of what it means, and it's just embarrassing that people keep complaining i'm misusing it!

Comment: Because, as already noted, things cannot actually speak.

Comment: well you're wrong according to the oed?

Comment: No, I am not. The definitions you rely on say nothing about speaking *literally* - and the answer given by WendyG explains clearly why such usage would be wrong.

Comment: if it's figurative the oed says it is.

Comment: This is not going anywhere. You either don't understand what *literally* means, or you think that things can actually speak.

Comment: i think things can literally speak, yes, see definition 15a below

Comment: @user3293056: I think don't use the same definitions of "literal" and "figurative" that other people do. If you stick to your unsual definition (which you have not made explicit to us), I don't think the discussion will make any sense.

Comment: this again, no i do, please stop projecting that mistake onto me, it's very confusing! @Cerberus figuration is a non-literal use. and literal use is covered by every literal definition in a dictionary!!

Comment: i think in fact you are mistakenly thinking that literal means "non conversational" it does not mean that, that is the incorrect use of "literal" and it is in fact all of you who, in their haste, have become mistaken!  @Cerberus

Comment: @user3293056: I notice you haven't provided the definitions of "literal" and "figurative" that you use.

Comment: i have indeed *already* defined 'literal': it is whatever appears in a dictionary under a literal and non-figurative definition. a "figure" is a figure of speech, a way of speaking that is out of the ordinary, due to being different from literal usage, as there defined @Cerberus

Comment: That is a wrong definition: in English, a dictionary is (or attempts to be) descriptive - it does not prescribe. No matter how many times you ask this, the answer is the same: the **only** literal sense of *speak* is when humans communicate by vibrating air using their speech organs. A speaking clock is figurative use. Even Stephen Hawking "spoke" figuratively only.

Comment: @user3293056: That is a circular definition. It doesn't really work. Why not try the relevant part of the OED entry on ***literal***:  *"...[pertaining] to the etymological or the relatively primary sense of a word..."*. This is the normal definition of the word in the present context (the context of classifying the various senses of a word). With regard to *speak*, it seems clear beyond doubt that its etymological and primary meaning is to utter words by emitting sound using one's mouth. It therefore seems impossible for *speak* to be used literally in *"facts speak for themselves"*.